# How to add a "remove button" at the right side of the hovering (or each) item of a wx.ComboBox popup

Tags: python, wxpython

What I want is a mean to remove an item from the combobox without having to add a separate remove button somewhere else. So I want a remove button to appear at the right side on a combobox dropdown item when I hover over my mouse pointer on it. And, it is also OK if all the items have remove button at the right side and do not need hovering.

The images bellow will illustrate what I am saying [...please ignore my mspaint skils]

[combobox with remove button for hovering item]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bAsMQ.jpg

[combobox with remove button for each item]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YhM5.jpg

[NOTE: Sorry, I cannot post images directly because it needs at least 10 reputation to post images.]

[I am new to python and wxpython. So please ignore my ignorance if any. And for the same reason any simple code sample will be greatly helpful.]

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

The `wx.ComboBox` does not have this feature. The wxPython GUI toolkit uses the target platform's native widgets. If those widgets don't support doing it, then neither does wxPython.

However, wxPython does have custom widgets or you could create your own widget to do this sort of thing.

I also think you could use a context-menu for this task. You would need to right-click to make it work. Another method would be to bind to a mouse event and try to figure out where in the widget you are, but I think that method would be error prone.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I am on Win 7 Pro 32bit, I am not sure msw have native support of it or not. I have seen several applications have it. I cannot tell which GUI they were using. But as you said if its possible by custom widgets, how to make custom widgets in wxpython ?? can you please elaborate or if possible, some code. I am thinking about try to get the DC and draw something and check when mouse pointer is on the right place, then highlight it with a another custom draw, then if clicked get a callback with the mouse click event. sounds very messy.

Comment: But is it the right approach? I mean are my thought on the right track ??? But if yes, I still have to figure out the how to get the particular DC, how to draw on it, etc etc. I will be bothering you peoples more often then... :D :D :D

Comment: I haven't seen a native widget that allows for this on Windows. But you can look at the custom widgets in wxPython. Everything in `wx.adv` are custom, for example

Comment: I have seen the wx.adv thing. And in wxpython custom widgets are simply templates I think. But I'm not gonna wait for someone to feed me. I'm gonna try to find food and feed myself. If any answer comes from this forum its highly appreciated. But I'm not gonna wait. If I find anything useful, I'll post here as answer. And thanks @Mike Driscoll for taking the time to help.